# Convert openssl command to php

Tags: php, openssl

i have line of command

```
echo -n 2bRePass1234 | openssl dgst -sha1 -binary | openssl enc -base64
```

output : 3O3bhZbGKheK+g/M4pp18AwGqq8= (28 char)

i need to convert it php

what i tried. openssl_encrypt need $iv and $key. i just use random_bytes because dont know whats is the default value like the command above

```
return base64_encode(
           openssl_encrypt(
                sha1('testPass1234'),
                'AES-128-CBC',
                random_bytes(16),
                OPENSSL_RAW_DATA,
                random_bytes(16)
            )
);
```

But its doest return same result as the command did.. is there any way just use default key and cipher to generate it?

Note: i put random_bytes(16) because i dont know what to fill it based on the command.

Comment: It `does` return the same result or `does not` return the same result ?

Comment: If it uses _random-bytes_ how could it return a constant value?

Comment: @LorinczyZsigmond @Bùi Đức Khánh i just use random_bytes because dont know whats is the default value like the command above. its just `openssl dgst -sha1 -binary | openssl enc -base64`.. and i need to convert it to php code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two things ...

1. You are doing a `dgst` (digest) in your first call of `openssl` therefore you cannot call `openssl_encrypt` in your php.
2. By doing a digest you does not need random bytes.

There are at least 2 ways to do it in php

1) Using sha1 function

```
php -r "var_dump(base64_encode(pack('H*', sha1('testPass1234'))));"
string(28) "wW+fqYWyUoXq+c76j0j2mnD5Oyc="
```

2) Using `openssl_digest` function

```
php -r "var_dump(base64_encode(pack('H*', openssl_digest('testPass1234', 'SHA1'))));"
string(28) "wW+fqYWyUoXq+c76j0j2mnD5Oyc="
```

They will both return the same. The string returned from `sha1` will be packed into a string of real bits and not treated as string.

PS: I saw you passed a different string in the command line sample and the php sample, but whenever passing the same string the results will be the same.

```
echo -n testPass1234 | openssl dgst -sha1 -binary | openssl enc -base64
wW+fqYWyUoXq+c76j0j2mnD5Oyc=
```

Hope it's what you whore looking for. Cheers!